# How to convert a existing react native navigation app to expo router app?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, expo-router

I'm new in *expo router* (and *react native* in general) need to know how to convert a existing react native navigation app to expo router app (I got this task for a existing app that is 1 year old using react native navigation),
*Expo docs not a beginner-friendly*

I have a big `index.tsx` in `AppNavigator` folder (Its a 1 year project in react navigation that I need to change to expo router)

And im not sure where to start or how to do that
anyone try to do it before?